# Find specific string with jquery

Tags: jquery

I use a 'change'-function to put the value of selectbox into an input

```
$("#afa_select").change(function() {
    var nd_value = $('#afa_select :selected').text();
    $("#nd_hidden").val(nd_value);
});
```

The options of the selectbox contain the following strings:

```
text 10 Jahre
another text 6 Jahre
just another text 12 Jahre
another text with a figure e.g. 1000 6 Jahre
another text with a figure e.g. 3234 6 Jahre
```

I need to find the number in front of the string " Jahre" and put this value into the input #nd_hidden.

Comment: is the position of "Jahre" always the same?

Comment: This isn't a jQuery thing, it's a JavaScript thing. What have you tried? Where are you getting stuck?

Comment: Can you use that number as the attribute for the options, it would be easier to read that way, just a suggestion. Other way is to do it with regex.

Comment: If 'Jahre' always going to be there you can simply do - nd_value[nd_value.length-7], but I would still do it regex way

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is trivial with a [regular expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions):

```
var text = "another text with a figure e.g. 1000 6 Jahre";
var result = /(\d+) +Jahre/.exec(text);
if (result) {
    console.log(result[1]); // "6"
}
```

If you need it as a number:

```
var num = parseInt(result[1], 10);
```

The regular expression says: "Find the first match in the string that's a series of digits followed by one or more spaces followed by the characters `Jahre` and capture the digits in a capture group." `result` will be `null` if no match was found. If a match is found, the contents of the first capture group are in `result[1]`.

Answer (score 2):

you could also split the string on a space and get the n-2 position if you don't want to use regular expressions.

```
var selectNumber = nd_value.split(" "); 
var yourNumber = selectNumber[selectNumber.length-2]; 

console.log(yourNumber);
```